# how to convert a dataframe to a list (problem with reset index)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am new to pandas and recently ran into a problem.I tried searching the net but couldnt find much.I have a dataframe like this

```
WeekDno   day
 2        Tue     5
 3        Wed    10
 5        Fri     5
```

i got it by doing this

```
g =  l.groupby("WeekDno").day.value_counts()
```

now when i try to convert it to a list by doing

```
g =  l.groupby("WeekDno").day.value_counts().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

i get an error of

```
cannot insert day, already exists
```

I tried removing reset_index() but then it gave me

```
[5, 10, 5]
```

but i wanted something like this

```
[[2,'Tue',5],[3,'Wed',10],[5,'Fri',5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) then use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
lst = g.rename(None).reset_index().to_numpy().tolist()
```

OR It is also possible to use `reset_index` directly but we have to specify the *unique name*:

```
lst = g.reset_index(name='day_count').to_numpy().tolist()
```

Another possible idea using `zip`:

```
lst = [[*x, y] for x, y in zip(g.index, g)]
```

Result:

```
print(lst)
[[2, 'Tue', 5], [3, 'Wed', 10], [5, 'Fri', 5]]
```